# Beautiful Soup and list issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Edit 2:

So the issue is the `for loop` in question never ran because the way I wrote it, when it didn't encounter the `Stats` link, it simply skipped over the `for loop` entirely.  I refactored it a bit as shown below.  I'm not sure its the most efficient way to do it but it works.  I may post a new question to determine if there is a better and cleaner way to write this.

```
        for span in team.find_all("span"):
            stats = span.find_all("a", href=True, text='Stats')
            if stats:
                for team_stats in stats:
                    team_stats_list.append(team_stats.get('href'))
            else:
                team_stats_list.append("NO STATS")
        print(team_stats_list)
```

Initial post below...

I can't figure out why my append isn't working like I am intending in this snippet of code:

```
        for team_stats in team.find_all("a", href=True, text='Stats'):
            stats_available = team_stats.get('href')
            if stats_available:
                team_stats_list.append(stats_available)
            else:
                team_stats_list.append("NO STATS")
        print(team_stats_list)
```

Essentially, I making sure that there is actually a `href` with the text of `Stats` being put into the `stats_available` variable.

If there is, I simply append the `stats_available` variable to the list.  If the variable is empty, I want to append the text `NO STATS` to the list instead.

The code is scrapping properly and getting the `href` (if its available) so that isn't the problem.  The problem is when there is no `href` called `Stats` then it is not appending the `NO STATS` text.  The list is simply empty.

Edit 1 - Whole function so far:

```
    source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.espn.com/college-football/teams').read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    page_source = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mod-container mod-open-list mod-teams-list-medium mod-no-footer"})
    for conference in page_source:
        conference_title = conference.div.h4.text
        team_name_list = []
        team_clubhouse_list = []
        team_stats_list = []
        print(conference_title)

        for team in conference.find_all("ul", {"class": "medium-logos"}):
            for team_title in team.find_all('h5'):
                team_name_list.append(team_title.text)
            print(team_name_list)

        for team clubhouse in team.find_all("a", {"class": "bi"}):
                team_clubhouse_list.append(team_clubhouse.get('href'))
            print(team_clubhouse_list)

        for team_stats in team.find_all("a", href=True, text='Stats'):
                stats_available = team_stats.get('href')
                if stats_available:
                    team_stats_list.append(stats_available)
                else:
                    team_stats_list.append("NO STATS")
            print(team_stats_list)
```

Comment: what's the url you're trying to scrape?

Comment: check the HTML code you are parsing to make sure it's what you expect (some times webservers will send different responses based on user-agent, for example)

Comment: @wpercy  I added the entire function so far as written under the initial question.

Comment: @Biggen from what I can tell, it's because all of the teams have a vaild href for their "team stats" link.

Comment: If there's no link with text = Stats, then the `for` loop doesn't loop over anything.

Comment: @wpercy Actually, there are no "Stats" link for any teams in the FCS conferences.  Only "Stats" for FBS schools

Comment: @Barmar I think this may be the issue.  I'll need to do some testing.

Comment: Yeah, I think Barmar got it.  My `for loop` doesn't encounter any link with `"a", href=True, text='Stats'` in it for all the FCS teams.  So nothing inside the `for loop` gets executed and the list stays empty.

Comment: @Barmar got it right.  The for loop was never running as the trigger needed `stats` to be in the page. I'll update the initial post with my refactored code.

Comment: If you want to show how you fixed it, post an answer, don't put the fix in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I was givng YOU the chance to post it as an answer. If you dont care about that, then Ill gladly post the answer...

Comment: I don't care about the +15, you can post your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.espn.com/college-football/teams').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
page_source = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mod-container mod-open-list mod-teams-list-medium mod-no-footer"})
for conference in page_source:
    conference_title = conference.div.h4.text
    team_name_list = []
    team_clubhouse_list = []
    team_stats_list = []
    print(conference_title)
    for team in conference.find_all("ul", {"class": "medium-logos"}):
        for team_title in team.find_all('h5'):
            team_name_list.append(team_title.text)

        print(team_name_list)
        for team_clubhouse in team.find_all("a", {"class": "bi"}):
            team_clubhouse_list.append(team_clubhouse.get('href'))

        print(team_clubhouse_list)
        for team_stats in team.find_all("a", href=True, text='Stats'):
            stats_available = team_stats.get('href')
            team_stats_list.append(stats_available)


        if(len(team_stats_list)==0):
             team_stats_list.append("NO STATS")

        print(team_stats_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is the for loop in question never ran because the way I wrote it. 
 When it didn't encounter the Stats link, it simply skipped over the for loop entirely. I refactored it a bit as shown below. I'm not sure its the most efficient way to do it but it works. I may post a new question to determine if there is a better and cleaner way to write this.

```
    for span in team.find_all("span"):
        stats = span.find_all("a", href=True, text='Stats')
        if stats:
            for team_stats in stats:
                team_stats_list.append(team_stats.get('href'))
        else:
            team_stats_list.append("NO STATS")
    print(team_stats_list)
```